R - Not sure about nested factor in linear mixed-effect model (lmer)
I am currently studying the presence of biological markers in post-mortem brains of healthy individuals compared to Alzheimer patients. I am not entirely sure I am using the correct design for my mixed model analysis.
The experimental design is quite simple. I have two groups of male and female subjects (Alzheimer group vs. control group). For each subject I have 3 (or more) brain sections in which I measure the presence of my biological marker.
I think for me it is important to consider the brain section because depending on the brain region I am looking at, it could influence the presence of my biomarker (that accumulates preferentially in some neurons, and all sections do not have the same neuronal density).
Ultimately, I would like to estimate the effect of the disease (group -> fixed), the effect of sex (sex -> fixed), and the interaction between group and sex. I might want to introduce more factors later (e.g., age of subject) but now I would like to keep my model as simple as possible to get an idea.
Sections are roughly taken from the same brain regions, but I don't have the exact brain regions/sections for all the subjects (same section number = exact same brain location).
|| ID |  Group  | Sex | Sec. | Measure ||
||----|---------|-----|------|---------||
|| s1 |  ctrl   |  M  |  37  |   324   ||
|| s1 |  ctrl   |  M  |  38  |   328   ||
|| s1 |  ctrl   |  M  |  40  |   379   ||
|| s2 |  ctrl   |  F  |  36  |   327   ||
|| s2 |  ctrl   |  F  |  40  |   360   ||
|| s2 |  ctrl   |  F  |  38  |   399   ||
|| s3 |  alzh   |  M  |  38  |   336   ||
|| s3 |  alzh   |  M  |  39  |   431   ||
|| s3 |  alzh   |  M  |  40  |   351   ||
|| s4 |  alzh   |  F  |  37  |   320   ||
|| s4 |  alzh   |  F  |  39  |   305   ||
|| s4 |  alzh   |  F  |  40  |   376   ||

This is my model at the moment:
model <- lmer(Measure ~ Group * Sex + (1 | ID) + (1 | Section), data)

Does section can be interpreted as nested? In that case, how should I write my model? (1 | ID / Section) does not work ... Not sure about random slope or intercept ...
I think it is important to keep the ID as random intercept. Is it?
Happy to provide more details ...

I think the proposed model seems like a reasonable start. It implies that participant and section are crossed random effects. See this great explanation by @RobertLong about what that means: Crossed vs nested random effects: how do they differ and how are they specified correctly in lme4?. There is extra information that you might consider including in the model such as brain region (sections are nested within regions?) & neuronal density (if it's is actually measured).

Thank you very much
